# Bluetooth Issues in 18.04 LTS

Tags: bluetooth, lts, 18.04

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and after the recent upgrade to the final release on April 26, 2018, I found that my laptop (Dell Inspiron 1440) was unable to connect to my Bluetooth speakers using a generic USB Bluetooth dongle which was earlier working perfectly in Ubuntu 17.10 Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1756824 Solution/Workaround in link above.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb`

Answer (score 1):

1. Install "synaptic".
2. Search synaptic to ensure "bluez" is installed.
3. Use synaptic to search and install "blueman".
4. reboot.
5. If no icon in task bar, search for "bluetooth manager" in your apps, and start it. Follow the screens to connect your device.

Comment: This is what I was going to recommend. I had to use the same steps to get an Apple Magic Mouse to work with 16.04. The built-in Bluetooth control applet is not versatile enough, but the BlueZ replacement works well.